# PrimeFaces <p:schedule> : rollback after invalid drag and drop

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, drag-and-drop, schedule

I'm using `<p:schedule>` and I note that after Drag&Drop a task, if I drop it on an invalid area (like the hour colum on the left), the task rollback to its original position.

```
<p:schedule value="#{myBean.myModel}">
    <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{myBean.onEventMove}"/>  
    <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{myBean.onEventResize}"/>
</p:schedule>
```

How can I call the rollback event ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from the backing bean, then you can adjust the start date and end date of moved `ScheduleEvent` in your `bean#onMove()` method. All you have to do is to add the **negative** value of dayDelta and minuteDelta to start and end dates and in `<p:ajax event="eventMove"` update the schedule component. Its not as nice as dropping the event on invalid area, but it's working.

Comment: That's I'm actually doing. But in fact, I want the rollback effect, not update the schedule component.